# R Data.Table Count and Store Unique Row

Tags: r, data.table

```
    data=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3),
    "score"=c(7,1,5,0,5,2,1),
    "WANT1"=c(2,2,4,4,4,4,1),
    "WANT2"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
"WANT3"=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

I have 'data' with 'student' and score' and wish to generate data column 'WANT1' that contains the number of rows for every student and 'WANT2' that equals to '1' if 'WANT1' > 1 and equals to '0' if 'WANT1' < 1. I hope for a data.table solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'student', get the number of rows (`n()`) as 'newwant1' and the check whether that value is greater than 1, coerce it to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(student) %>% 
    mutate(newwant1 = n(), newwant2 = +(newwant1 > 1))
```

---

If we use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, c("newwant1", "newwant2", "newwant3") := 
     .(.N, +(.N > 1),  min(score)), 
               by = student]
data
#   student score WANT1 WANT2 WANT3 newwant1 newwant2 newwant3
#1:       1     7     2     1     1        2        1        1
#2:       1     1     2     1     1        2        1        1
#3:       2     5     4     1     0        4        1        0
#4:       2     0     4     1     0        4        1        0
#5:       2     5     4     1     0        4        1        0
#6:       2     2     4     1     0        4        1        0
#7:       3     1     1     0     1        1        0        1
```

Comment: do you know data.table solution

Comment: this is perfect thank you--and my last question is, how can i identify a data.table solution to store the minimum score for each id as shown in updated sample data file 'WANT3'? i forget to add this at the beginning

Comment: WANT3 finds the lowest score for every student and reports it in the column. so student 1 score 7 and 1 so it is a 1. student 2 scored a lowest score of 0 so their value is a 0

Comment: thank you i realize this in my real data i have 'na' so i just had to set na.omit to true thank you. i think maybe that is sarcasm =)

Comment: @bvowe `min` have `na.rm` argument, so you can use `min(score, na.rm = TRUE)`